# Whats more pythonic? Change in-place or return value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a quick question.

Is it more pythonic to have values initialized by a returning func like this:

```
class Game:

    def __init__(self, AMOUNT_OF_PLAYERS = 2, AMOUNT_OF_CARDS = 7):
        self.draw_stack = create_draw_stack()
        self.play_stack = [self.draw_stack.pop()]

def create_draw_stack():
    VALUES = list(range(1, 10))
    COLORS = ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green"]
    return [Card(value, color) for value in VALUES for color in COLORS]
```

Or should it look more like this:

```
class Game:

    def __init__(self, AMOUNT_OF_PLAYERS = 2, AMOUNT_OF_CARDS = 7):
        self.draw_stack = []
        self.play_stack = []
        self.create_draw_stack()
        self.create_play_stack()

    def create_draw_stack(self):
        VALUES = list(range(1, 10))
        COLORS = ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green"]
        cards = [Card(value, color) for value in VALUES for color in COLORS]
        self.draw_stack = cards

    def create_play_stack(self):
        self.play_stack = [self.draw_stack.pop()]
```

I couldn't find anything on this particular question online. Is there like a rule of thumb to figure out questions like this intuitively?

Thanks.

Comment: It's unpythonic to think that functional paradigm is more pythonic than imperative or otherwise

Comment: So you're saying the 2nd way is correct?

Comment: Btw, I don't think that. I was asking which is correct :)

Comment: Both are correct. Just make sure that the docstring reflects what the function is doing. IMHO, the first one is nicer, as you don't have to look at the `create` method at all to know what the other code is doing, but that purely my opinion.

Comment: FWIW : using ALL_UPPER names for variables and arguments is not pythonic.

Comment: @Ingaz where have you seen anything functional in the OP's code ??? Also and FWIW: despite having a restricted support for functional programming, Python IS an imperative language, definitly.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Although almost everybody today has his own definition of "functional programming":   `def create_draw_stack`  is quite functional even for hardcore FP-ers

Comment: @Ingaz hardcore FP-ers would not even consider using a for loop (you have to use recursion), and let's not talk about local variables <g>. More seriously: this is plain ordinary imperative programming - even if the function has no side effects (which isn't even garanteed since we don't have the definition of `Card()`, which might as well write to a database for all we know), it's not enough to qualify as "functional programming". And the `Game` class is nothing functionnal either (classes ? What do you mean classes ? No mutable state allowed here <g>).

Comment: @MarcelB that's for module-level or class-level (pseudo) constants. Local names are not concerned, and specially not function arguments.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Following your logic Haskel is not FP-enough. But anyway: a) this question is in area of psychology and/or personal beliefs, b) I'm not an expert in psychology or religion, c) you are free to choose any definition of FP

Comment: @Ingaz I'm afraid you might have missed the semi-humoristic tone of my previous comments ;-) Truth is that I don't see anything specially "functional" in op's first snippet - you'll find very similar functions in any purely imperative/procedural code -  but it could indeed be found in functional code too so if you really want to label it as "functional", well, you are free to choose your own definition of "FP" too ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To illustrate Slam's answer with a pythonic solution:

```
class Game:

    VALUES = list(range(1, 10))
    COLORS = ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green"]

    @classmethod
    def create_draw_stack(cls):
        return  [Card(value, color) for value in cls.VALUES for color in cls.COLORS]       

    def __init__(self, players_count=2, cards_count=7):
        self.draw_stack = self.create_draw_stack()
        self.play_stack = [self.draw_stack.pop()]
```

Also, you asked:

> Is there like a rule of thumb to figure out questions like this intuitively?

The "intuitively" part is a matter of experience mostly ("experience" not being the same as "time spent doing something" - it also implies reading, experimenting, thinking, etc).

wrt/ "rule of thumb":

- high cohesion: one "unit" - be it a module, class, method or function - should be about one thing and only one thing (sometimes this "one thing" might be rather wide but anyway)
- locality: things that work together should be kept together (so you don't have to open a dozen files in your editor to find out how the whole thing work)
- low coupling: one "unit" should directly depend on as few other units as possible
- readability: the code should be as obvious and readable as possible (ok, some subjective parts here)
- testability: the code should be easy to test in isolation (cf "low coupling")
- simplicity: the code should be as simple as possible according to the problem's complexity.
- usability: your "unit" API should be designed to be as easy as possible to use for the client code

Comment: Why did you change `pop()` to `pop(0)`? Should not matter from which side of the stack you draw cards, and `pop()` should be faster (although strictly speaking both are O(1) if the size of the deck is bounded) (Well, in fact, it _does_ matter since OP does not shuffle the deck...)

Comment: @tobias_k a mere typo I'm afraid (fixed, thanks for spotting it).

Comment: Thank you, especially for your listing of pythonic thinking!

Comment: @MarcelB you're welcome - but note that there's nothing python-specific here actually - those "rules" apply to just any language -, it's only "pythonic" in the sense that Python's philosophy highly values readability and simplicity, which both imply good design and clean implementation.

Answer (score 3):

It's not much about being "pythonic", rather just composition question (and mind you, that's heavy-opinionionated).

About your code. What's good about approach #2: all code related to `Game` is "encapsulated" into single class (at least, it lives in same place). This makes it easy to manage in future — easy to find everything that creates/mutates `Game`.

What's good about approach #1: you have more "pure" function, that can be re-used later, and it's a little bit easier to test in isolation. Re-usability is good thing — in theory — but overthinking it and making pre-mature optimizations is bad idea, especially for price of readability.

One thing that you can do to combine both: keep "stateless" deck creation instead of mutating object state, and call it in `__init__`, but make your `create_draw_stack` part of class (i.e. make it `@staticmethod`) to indicate that stack is used somewhere in scope of class, and [so far] it's part of `Game`'s logic.

Comment: +1, one thing to mention in favor of the #1 or having it like a @staticmethod - the state of the class is not mutated outside of `__init__` - very nice when you have to maintain the code - "mutable" classes are often a problem when code is evolving

Comment: Absolutely true. I mentioned this (probably implicitly) as part of "easier to test". I strongly believe that once people starting writing most basic tests, mutating approaches becoming very clear pain in er... project.

Comment: Thank you a lot :)!